# Linking multiple custom UITableViewCell's to single xib

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**Question**

I'm creating a re-usable custom UITableViewCell and then subclassing it for re-use. How do I set these various subclasses to link to the same xib file?

**Background**

Let's call my custom UITableViewCell `PickerTableViewCell`. This cell includes a `UIPickerView`, as well as all the implementations as to how the picker view looks and behaves. When I want to use this cell, the only thing I need to give it is the data for the picker view. So I subclass `PickerTableViewCell`, then simply create the data source I need and assign it to the picker view. So far this has all worked well.

Here are the relevant parts of `PickerTableViewCell`:

```
class PickerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var picker: UIPickerView! = UIPickerView()
    var pickerDataSource: PickerViewDataSource!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 40, width: 0, height: 0))
        self.picker.delegate = self

        self.assignPickerDataSource()
    }

    // Must be overriden by child classes

    func assignPickerDataSource() {
        fatalError("Must Override")
    }
```

Here is an example of a subclass:

```
class LocationPickerTableViewCell: PickerTableViewCell {

    override func assignPickerDataSource() {
        self.pickerDataSource = LocationPickerDataSource()
        self.picker.dataSource = self.pickerDataSource
    }
}
```

**Problem**

Since I am using these cells all over the place, with different data sources, I created a xib file which defines how the cell looks called `PickerTableViewCell.xib`, and assign it to the class `PickerTableViewCell`. In the view controllers I want to use it for, I register the cell with the table view inside `viewDidLoad()`. Then, inside `func tableView(_:, cellForRowAt)` I dequeue the subclass I want like this:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier") as! LocationPickerTableViewCell
return cell
```

This is where the problem happens. The cell that is created is a `PickerTableViewCell`, not its subclass `LocationPickerTableViewCell`. This runs into the fatal error I placed in the parent class which is overriden by the child class.

The only way I have found to solve this is to create a separate xib file for each subclass I want to create, and assign it to the relevant subclass. While this solution *does* work, it feels wrong to have all of these xib files which are practically identical (except for which class they are assigned to) inside my project.

Is there a way I can overcome this problem, and have all of these cells link to the same single xib file?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Don't think there's anyway to do it, either have it layout by code, or duplicate Xib, or use extension

Comment: Why bother with the subclasses?  If the only difference is the data source, assign the datasource in `cellForRowAt`

Comment: @Paulw11 that's something I hadn't considered.. that would work for some subclasses such as LocationPickerTableViewCell above, however some others have extra functionality where subclasses works better

Comment: @RyanSaffer load Xib view by `Bundle.main.loadNibNamed' method in cell class, by this you can add same Xib view in multiple class.

Comment: @Rocky this seems like a good option but I have tried and am running into all sorts of issues such as '[<UITableViewCell 0x7fc59a0d1a00> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key headerLabel.' ... any chance you could give some sort of example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add view loaded by xib to `UITableViewCell` classes in which you want to use it.

1. Create your xib as per your require design, in your example `PickerTableViewCell.xib`
2. Create `UITableViewCell` sub-classes in which you want to use that view. I am using `FirstTableViewCell` & `SecondTableViewCell` for this.

in constructor of table cell load the xib and add it to table cell.

```
let nib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PickerTableViewCell", owner: nil, options: nil)
        if let view = nib?.first as? UIView{
            self.addSubview(view)
        }
```

if xib have any `@IBOutlet` then get them by `viewWithTag` function and assign to class variables

```
if let label = self.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel{
            self.label = label
        }
```

`override` `reuseIdentifier` var of each tableviewCell subclass with different name

```
override var reuseIdentifier: String?{
    return "FirstTableViewCell"
}
```

Now You can use these classes where you want, for using this follow below steps:

register this tableviewCell subclass with xib with tableview:

```
tableView.register(FirstTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"PickerTableViewCell")
```

now in `cellForRowAt indexPath` method use it.

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FirstTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? FirstTableViewCell
if cell == nil {
    cell = FirstTableViewCell()
}
cell?.label?.text = "FirstTableViewCell"
```

Comment: This solution has worked perfectly! I have a single xib, and able to use it as needed by any class, even subclasses. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use subclassing to assign different data sources.

#### Approach 1: Assign `pickerDataSource` in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`

In the table view controller, you need to assign `pickerDataSource`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier") as! PickerTableViewCell
    cell.pickerDataSource = LocationPickerDataSource()

    return cell
}
```

Handle additional work needed after the assignment of `pickerDataSource` with a `didSet`.

```
class PickerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var picker: UIPickerView! = UIPickerView()
    var pickerDataSource: PickerViewDataSource! {
        didSet {
            self.picker.dataSource = self.pickerDataSource
        }
    }

    …
}
```

#### Approach 2: Extend `PickerTableViewCell` in all the needed ways.

Here instead of subclassing add the needed logic to a uniquely named setup method each defined in their own extension.

```
extension PickerTableViewCell {

    func setupLocationPickerDataSource() {
        self.pickerDataSource = LocationPickerDataSource()
        self.picker.dataSource = self.pickerDataSource
    }

}
```

then in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier") as! PickerTableViewCell
    cell.setupLocationPickerDataSource()

    return cell
}
```

Comment: thanks for such a detailed answer! While these approaches come very close, I have not marked it as correct for a couple of reasons:
1. My subclasses have additional functionality that override certain methods, something that cannot be achieved using extensions.
2. Given problem 1, the dequeued cell is still a `PickerTableViewCell`, not a `LocationPickerTableViewCell`.

See the answer marked as correct, which was able to link to a single xib while keeping my subclass design.

Thanks!!